# jquery serialize don't work well with angular material tabs

Tags: jquery, angular, serialization, tabs, angular-material

I'm using angular material tabs inside form tag and [this is my code exemple](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qeeo5b) : 
So the problem is when I try to serialize the form using jquery in my submit function like this:

```
submit(f: HTMLElement){
   let serializedForm = $(f).serialize()
   this.serialisedData = serializedForm
}
```

Only the the fields in the active tab are being serialized and ignore the fields in the other tabs, alghout the normal behaviour of this function is to serialize all the inputs inside the form.

Why it's not working as expected?

Answer (score 1):

try this on ts:

```
submit(){

   this.serialisedData =  this.form.value
}
```

on html:

```
 {{serialisedData | json}}
```

Comment: When I tried this way, the output result for "this.form.value" is not serialized but the json data like this { "code": null, "target": null, "startDate": null, "endDate": null } . I want the output string with this format code=&target=&start=&end=

Comment: JSON.stringify(this.form.value)